# How do I stop an animatePNG animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this library to animate PNG image: https://github.com/pixelmatrix/animatePNG

The source code lists a stop() method but how do I call it? I want to stop the animation.

Source: https://github.com/pixelmatrix/animatePNG/blob/master/animatePNG.js

Comment: $("#container").animatePNG().stop(), I think.

Comment: It seems to be defined as [`$.fn.animatePNG.stop($el)`](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/animatePNG/blob/master/animatePNG.js#L98).  So, `$fn.animatePNG.stop($("#container"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a little odd but I do it like this:

```
var $c = $("#container").animatePNG("spinner.png", 37, 37, 11, {horizontal: false});
$c.animatePNG.stop($c); // stop animation
```

Comment: or `$.fn.animatePNG.stop($c);`

Comment: @JennaSmith never tried. Or this: `clearInterval($c.data("animation").t)`

Comment: @letiagoalves: I'd suggest using their `stop` method.  Just in case they decide to change where `t` is stored in a newer version.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you're right. Also it would make more sense just `$c.animatePNG.stop()`, without arguments. but it is required

Comment: @letiagoalves: I don't know why they did it like that.  Most plugins usually do: `$c.animatePNG('stop')`.

Comment: $.fn.animatePNG.stop(mySpinner) worked, as well as mySpinner.animatePNG.stop(mySpinner). I prefer the former! Thanks everybody.